# Bootstrap Responsive Menu Not Expanding Correctly

Tags: mobile, bootstrap-4, menu, responsive

I've modified the responsive Bootstrap menu a bit, and the results aren't quite what I wanted. I was trying to get the entire menu to render on a single line, and there are more menu items than can render in the 1140px container, so I expanded the container a bit. When resizing the browser, I'm breaking at 1260px. The menu is hidden and the hamburger icon for the mobile drop-down menu appears as expected, but if I click the hamburger, the menu is displayed inline instead of expanding the mobile menu. At least until I get to the 992px breakpoint. If I remove the Bootstrap rules for the 992px breakpoint, the menu doesn't render incorrectly when clicking the burger icon, but doesn't appear normally, either. I'm not sure exactly how to fix this. There's a link below to the jsFiddle demonstrating the issue. When the burger icon is first displayed as the browser resizes, clicking on it will show the problem. Narrow the window further, and it works as expected.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 90%;
  width: 90%;
}

@media (max-width: 1260px) {
  .navbar-header {
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar-toggler {
    display: block!important;
  }
  .navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  }
  .collapse:not(.show) {
    display: none!important;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">

  <div class="container horizontal-padding-0">

    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand mb-3">
      <h2>TITLE</h2>
    </a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

    <div id="navbarNav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">

      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="menu-links">AAAA</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="menu-links">BBBBBBBBB BBBBBBBB</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="menu-links">CCCCCCCCCC</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="menu-links">DDDDDDD</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="menu-links">EE EEEEE</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="menu-links">FFFFFFF</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="menu-links">GGGGG</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>

  </div>

</nav>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Indurate/q2fcLpyw/4/)

Answer (score 0):

OK, that was pretty simple. I just had to change the value of the "xl" breakpoint variable in _variables.scss from 1200px to the width I needed.